# Best PHP download to keep all my options open?

Tags: php, windows-vista, installation, development-environment

In the past, I used WAMPserver on windows to parse PHP for me. This is a pre-configured package, focussed on working with MySQL.

When I tried to run PostgreSQL, I got error messages that said that my version of PHP wasn't compiled to work with PostgreSQL.

So, I've recently uninstalled WAMP and every associated with it. I've downloaded Apache 2.2.11 with openSSL, installed as admin(you know, run the command prompt as administrator, cd to the directory where the download was done and have it executed, so the install was done as admin).

That's that. I now have Apache installed, "it works" shows up, so I'm that far.

Now I'm wondering, do I download the exe and install, or the zip, or something else.
What is the best thing to do to make sure that the PHP on my system can handle everything I can ever throw at it?

Also, PHP first, or MySQL/Postgre first.
And lastly, what about PEAR? I need PEAR installed, which isn't standard on Windows. I'm guessing the pear.bat file in the PHP downloads will do that for me?

EDIT: I see one close vote, yet no comment as to why. It makes me wonder how people who are so lazy and rude got to have somany points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend downloading the zip package, as configuring php is not really that difficult, and it allows you to add features as needed.

As for whether first to install php or MySQL/PostgreSQL, - it does not really matter. You can install them in any order.

Your guess regarding PEAR is quite correct

Answer (score 3):

i haven't used wamp before, so i can't comment on that

i do however use xampp which sounds very similar

in xampp if i want to enable postgres support i edit the php.ini file and uncomment the postgres section of the ini file, same with any of the extensions that i need

perhaps this might be an alternative you can try if you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to setup a HTTP server/PHP/database machine. Sometimes the behaviour of your development setup will differ from the live server's.

I would recommend finding out the setup your web host is using, then getting a vmware [appliance](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/) image that fits that as close as possible and get any additional software using it's package manager (which is easier that installing stuff on Windows).

Setup a file sharing link between the VM and the host, make sure you can view the VM's port 80 in a browser running in your host OS and you're set.